# .asc conversion to .tif file(raster)

Tags: r, ascii, raster, terra

I am not familiar with .asc file and trying to convert it to raster. [Extended Reconstructed Sea Surface Temperature (ERSST) dataset](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/extended-reconstructed-sst) was downloaded from [ERSST repo](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/ersst/v5/ascii/)

There is some info for the dataset in its README file:

```
filename convention:

(1) ERSST 

ersst.VERSION.yyyy.asc
yyyy=year

Units: isst=100 degree C
Missing value=-9999

(2) grid information
latitude: -88.0, increase northward per 2 degree, to +88.0
longitude:  0.0, increase eastward per 2 degree, to 358.0
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
url <- "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/ersst/v5/ascii/ersst.v5.1854.asc"
f <- basename(url)
download.file(url, f, mode="wb")

a<- terra::rast(f)
plot(a)
```

I got warning messages when use `a=terra::rast(f)`,for example, and `plot(a)`:

```
1: Failed to read scanline 672. (GDAL error 3) 
2: ersst.v5.1854.asc, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 672: Failed to read scanline 672. (GDAL error 1) 
3: [plot] SpatRaster has no cell values
```

Not sure if it is something related to the projection system. If it is the case, which projection reference I should use for this global dataset?

Comment: You should provide code as well if possible. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969109/setting-values-of-layer-of-spatraster or this  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437943/r-terra-crop-spatraster-has-no-values   may be related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asc data use a non-standard format. It would be easy enough to read if you had to, but in this case you can use the NetCDF files instead; and that is much simpler:

Download example file

```
url <- "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/ersst/v5/netcdf/ersst.v5.185401.nc"
f <- basename(url)
download.file(url, f, mode="wb")
```

Open it as a SpatRaster

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(f)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 89, 180, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 2, 2  (x, y)
#extent      : -1, 359, -89, 89  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#sources     : ersst.v5.185401.nc:sst  
#              ersst.v5.185401.nc:ssta  
#varnames    : sst (Extended reconstructed sea surface temperature) 
#              ssta (Extended reconstructed SST anomalies) 
#names       : sst_lev=0, ssta_lev=0 
#unit        :  degree_C,   degree_C 
#time (raw)  : 0
```

Note that longitude goes from -1 to 359. You can use use `rotate` to get more standard longitudes; and you can write it to a GeoTiff at the same time.

```
rotate(x, filename="ersst.v5.185401.tif")

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 89, 180, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 2, 2  (x, y)
#extent      : -181, 179, -89, 89  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : ersst.v5.185401.tif 
#names       : sst_lev=0, ssta_lev=0 
#min values  :  -1.80000,  -4.958618 
#max values  :  32.09937,   2.676313 
#time (raw)  : 0
```

But note that it still is not what it ought to be (-180, 180). You could use resample to fix that.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I was unable to rasterize .nc file at beginning(which gives error message ```.nc not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)``` and tried to update the terra package) , but turns out the issue is that I did not define mode as "wb" when downloading files.

Comment: or even terra::project(terra::rast(file.path("/vsicurl", url)), terra::rast(res = 2))